# Why Marshal.Sizeof does not work for strings?

Tags: c#

```
string s = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(s)); // gives error
```

Marshal.Sizeof works for other data-types like int, char etc. but does not works for string datatype. Any specific reason for this?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/

Comment: It doesn't work even for arrays, bitArray and other reference types.

Answer (score 5):

String is reference type (`class`) not value type (`struct`).

[Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method accepts an instance of a structure, which can be a reference type or a boxed value type. The layout must be sequential or explicit.